# regex compiling in intellij idea but not in android studio and showing

Tags: java, android, regex, syntax-error

I'm running this code block in java ide i.e. intellij idea it is working fine and also tried some online regex matcher there it also working
but when i run this in android studio it is showing error block of code is

```
public static String gettime(String temp){

    String result  = new String();

    String time=new String();
    time = ".*([0-1][0-9][:][0-5][0-9][:][0-5][0-9]).*";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(time);//error during compilation
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);

    if(matcher.matches()){
        result = matcher.group(1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and the error is

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR
.*([0-1][0-9][:][0-5][0-9][:][0-5][0-9]).*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you switch from `[:]` to `:`

```
time = ".*([0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]).*";
```

escaping also works:

```
time = ".*([0-1][0-9][\\:][0-5][0-9][\\:][0-5][0-9]).*";
```

not sure why android does not like `[:]` but it should be the same as `:`